Can't send UDP packet via DDNS domain name
I'm trying to set up WireGuard and am running into multiple issues. To debug, I'm using WireShark to verify if any packets make it to my server, which runs on a laptop in a private network behind a DDNS thingy, with port forwarding from the router enabled.
When I run
nc -u <current IPv4> 51820 < /dev/random

WireShark shows those packets arriving just fine. But doing
nc -u <DDNS name> 51820 < /dev/random

NetCat exits immediately, sometimes without error, sometimes with error 130.
Any clue why that might be?

Can you try it from outside your network (perhaps by using cell data, maybe hotspot mode)? If it works from outside the network but not inside, it indicates that your NAT gateway does not support NAT hairpinning (also called NAT loopback or NAT reflection). You might need to upgrade your router to something that supports NAT hairpinning, possibly by flashing open source Linux-based router firmware like OpenWrt onto it, or just by buying a new router that has factory firmware that supports it.

I figured out what the problem is, but I don't see a nice solution. My server (old laptop) doesn't support IPv6, but apparently clients use that to connect. When I add the -4 flag to NetCat, it works fine. But rather, I need that IPv6 traffic to reach my IPv4 server, or indicate wireguard clients to only use IPv4 via config. Any chances?

Maybe reconfigure your DDNS client to not register a v6 address if you're not really supporting v6. But even if your DNS lookup returns a v6 address, it's weird to me that a client would prefer v6 and fail rather than trying both Happy Eyeballs-style.

yes, it would be nice if clients were smarter, but netcat, sofcat, ncat and wireguard all agree on just failing...
